# How to create a PropertyMap for a boost graph using listS as vertex container?

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I have a boost graph defined as

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS,
        boost::undirectedS, CoordNode, CoordSegment> BGraph;
typedef boost::graph_traits<BGraph>::vertex_descriptor  VertexDesc;
BGraph _graph;
```

and I want to know the connected components of same graph with

```
 int num = boost::connected_components(_graph, propMap);
```

I already tried to create the required writable property map (propMap) with

```
typedef  std::map<VertexDesc, size_t> IndexMap;
IndexMap mapIndex;
boost::associative_property_map<IndexMap> propMap(mapIndex);
VertexIterator di, dj;
boost::tie(di, dj) = boost::vertices(_graph);
for(di; di != dj; ++di){
    boost::put(propMap, (*di), 0);
}
```

but that doesn't work; I get compilations errors.

If the vertex container would be vecS, it would be easier, because a simple array or vector would suffice. But what am I supposed to pass to this function if I have listS as the vertex container?

How can I create the necessary writable property map? Can somebody give me an example?

Comment: Your compilation errors (that you should always add if you really want to get help) are due to the fact that your graph does not have a vertex index map (that is required by the default color map used by the [`connected_components`](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html) algorithm). Your propMap is fine (although you don't need to initialize it), you just have to create a similar index map (this one needs to be initialized) and pass it to the algorithm using the named parameters. [Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3DPGun$0) is an example.

Comment: @llonesmiz Thanks! Now I finally figured out what the named parameters are about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works!

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list
    <boost::setS, boost::listS,
        boost::undirectedS, 
        boost::no_property,
        boost::no_property> Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator VertexIterator;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor   VertexDesc;
    typedef std::map<VertexDesc, size_t> VertexDescMap; 

Graph graph;

...


VertexDescMap idxMap;
boost::associative_property_map<VertexDescMap> indexMap(idxMap);
VertexIterator di, dj;
boost::tie(di, dj) = boost::vertices(_graph);
for(int i = 0; di != dj; ++di,++i){
    boost::put(indexMap, (*di), i);
}


std::map<VertexDesc, size_t> compMap;
boost::associative_property_map<VertexDescMap> componentMap(compMap);            
boost::associative_property_map<VertexDescMap>& componentMap;

boost::connected_components(_graph, componentMap, boost::vertex_index_map(indexMap));
```